# Convert String to filter

Tags: r

I need to do a looping to change only the last digit of the year to change the filter of my query to generate a histogram for each year, I can do this:

instead of this:

```
hist(dados$Avg_Intervalo_DataInicio_DataFim[dados$Periodo==2013], col = "gray")
hist(dados$Avg_Intervalo_DataInicio_DataFim[dados$Periodo==2014], col = "gray")
hist(dados$Avg_Intervalo_DataInicio_DataFim[dados$Periodo==2015], col = "gray")
```

...

i need this

```
for (1 in 1:10) {

base <- "dados$Avg_Intervalo_DataInicio_DataFim[dados$Periodo==201"
base <- paste(base,i,"]",sep = "");base
# "dados$Avg_Intervalo_DataInicio_DataFim[dados$Periodo==2011]"

hist(base, col = "gray") #Error here, because r do not understand that variable "base" is a query, it's understand that is a string

}
```

Somebody can help me?

Comment: It see,s you are looking for a bar plot with the year being categorical.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generally, such conversion is not possible.

It is possible to work a way around this. When you know the years you can put them into a symbol and then create a for loop with it.

```
years <- c(2013:2023)

for (year in years) {
   hist(dados$Avg_Intervalo_DataInicio_DataFim[dados$Periodo==year], col = "gray")
}
```